# C# Optional parameters / multiple required

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Is it possible to get a requirement for 2 optional parameters together? Here's an example:

```
public void ParamChoise(string A, bool B = false, string C = "Y")
    {
        // Stuff here
    }
```

Where B is optional, I want the function to require C if B is true. From my Logic something like that:

```
public void ParamChoise(string A, (bool B = false, string C = "Y"))
```

Couldnt find anything by googling. One possible way for me would be:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// If you want behaviour XXX to be enabled, please enter "C" for usage.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="A"></param>
        /// <param name="C"></param>
        public void ParamChoise(string A, string C = "Y")
        {
            // Stuff here
        }
```

For sure I could give my function a comment like this, but writing a comment for an unlogical given parameter feels bad to me.

This case is maybe a bad example but Im sure I'll run into this again in the future.

Thanks very much :).

**EDIT TO CLEAR THINGS:**
Possible combination for the parameters:

- A only
- A & (B & C)
- NOT A & B
- NOT A & C (Because B gives the point if C is needed)

Comment: No, you can´t do param-checking in the method-header. However you may introduce two overloads for this. Anyway you may also throw an excption if one of the arguments is missing whilst the other one is provided.

Comment: But you can always determine if `C` is required before you invoke `ParamChoice`.

Comment: This will be really bad from readability point of view. Just have explicit methods with unique names; transfer the logic to the caller.

Comment: In any case, you have to ask yourself if it is better to have two different functions for "B=true" and for "B=false"; of course, they may call the same private function to their actual work.

Comment: `NOT A & B` - does this mean `NOT` as in a boolean `!` or as in "I dont want"

Comment: @Jamiec As "I dont want" ^^. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Ah right - you'll run into problems because 1 and 3 have a single string parameter - you'll need to use different names for thos emethods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need the old way - method overloading.

```
// b = true
public void ParamChoise(string A, string C)

// b = false
public void ParamChoise(string A)
```

They should call a private version of your original

```
private void ParamChoiseInternal(string A, bool B = false, string C = "")
```

You should ensure that you're giving the 2 public methods a name that accurately conveys their meaning - that will help the programmer (probably you, I know) call the right method for their current state.

---

After update

Same as above, names reflect requirement, and you should still be able to call your original private method. The overloads ensure your consistency

```
public void AOnly(string A)
public void AAndBAndC(string A, bool B, string C)
```

Struggling to decipher these 2:

> NOT A & B WITHOUT C !!!
>   NOT A AND C (Because B gives the point if C is needed)

Comment: And, if B describes some important property, this could be reflected in two different names for the two methods.

Comment: He wants B to be optional, until C is given. That simply isn't possible without logic.

Comment: @MeirionHughes No, thats upside down. I want C to fall out until B is given.

Comment: ok, but this answer completely omits C in the second case (b = false)... It still needs to be there, its just optional when b = true.

Comment: If the first function would be `(string A, bool B, string C)` wouldnt that be the solution? It would require C, if B would be given...!?

Comment: Yeah thats it. For your last one I can use the same name right? I mean I can call both functions "myFunc"?

Comment: @C4ud3x - you can overload a method (re-use its name) as long as the parameters are different types. For example you **couldn't** have `MyFunc(string A)` and `MyFunc(string C)` - the parameters are the same types. This is also why you may like to use *different* names for your public methods to convey their behaviour to the user of the method

Comment: @Jamiec Oh alright. Thanks for getting this clear. I guess Im done in here now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [named arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

```
public void ParamChoise(string A = "", bool B = false, string C = "Y") {...}

// call it
ParamChoise(A: "123");
ParamChoise(C: "123");
ParamChoise(C: "123", A: "123");
ParamChoise(B: true, C: "123", A: "123");
```

I found this extremely useful for methods with many optional parameters.

With explicit parameter name specifying you are free to add new optional parameters **in any place** later without destroying existing code.

Comment: But this isnt fixing my thing. Your 2nd 3rd call shouldnt be possible. Check my edit on the question.

Comment: Then you have to use overriding (where you expose only valid combinations) and calling this `ParamChoise` (which accept anything), just make it non `public`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather you want C to optional WHEN b is false; AS an exercise in method over-loading, I think the closest you'll get is:

```
void ParamChoise(string A, string C)
void ParamChoise(string A, bool B = true, string C = "Y")
```

You still have to decide in the caller whether to supply the Bool... which makes it pointless as you can now do:

```
void ParamChoiseBIsFalse(string A, string C)
void ParamChoiseBIsTrue(string A, string C = "Y")
```

You've just got complex logic that cannot be translated directly into a simple overload. You either put that logic in the callee or caller

Comment: Yeah in case of the bool its pointless. But in general Ill keep your answers to the future where I maybe face another problem where I need those conditions being possible. So the first example without the optional C is correct. Anyway, already picked my answer as @Jamiec was faster.